# ошибка при импорте vue-trix в nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, ssr

Я пытаюсь подключить библиотеку vue-trix в nuxt, по официальной доке - https://github.com/hanhdt/vue-trix#getting-started. Делаю как сказано там через плагины, и потом пытаюсь вывести на странице компонент, но мне выбрасывает что windows in not defined, проблема не решается, помогите кто сможет, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

window - это окружение браузера. На сервере нет этого окружения. Если какой-либо метод, на сервере, будет обращаться к окружению браузера - будет ошибка. Что у Вас и происходит.  Не все пакеты/библиотеки расчитаны  для использования при ssr

Comment: я уже понял, я обернул в тег client-only и ошибка ушла, но проблема в том что нет реактивности, я никак не могу получить значение которое ввожу в редактор. Можете протестировать у себя, может разберётесь?